# Seeking help for a C# ASP.NET Core Web App project

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a button click event handler to ASP.NET Core Web App but I am not sure of how to do that. So far, here is what I have done:-

In Index.cshtml file, I have added the following line of code:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="Click_Submit_Button">Submit</button>
```

In the Index.cshtml.cs file, I have added the following code template to represent the event handler:

```
public void Click_Submit_Button() 
{

}
```

The name onclick in the Index.cshtml code is giving an error that the name does not exist in the current context. I am thinking that this is not the right name and that if I use the right name to represent the button click event handler, the issue will be resolved. If that is indeed the case, I would like to know the right name for the event handler. If that is not the case and/or there are other issues in what I have done, I would appreciate any help in letting me know how to go about resolving the issues and adding the button click event handler correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below piece of code shows if you click on the client-side and do action on the client-side

```
<button name="button" onClick="check()">Click</button>

<script>
function onClick()
{

}
</script>
```

In `onClick` function use ajax call and fetch data from server side, without refreshing web page.
For reference [Ajax Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good to know that

Answer (score 1):

The below piece of code shows if you click on the client-side and do action on the server-side.

Code in .cshtml file

```
<button name="button" asp-action="check">Click</button>
```

Code in Controller

```
public IActionResult ButtonClick()
{
    return View();
}
public IActionResult check()
{
   //Do your actions here.
    return RedirectToAction("ButtonClick");
}
```